# Check if timestamp is after 12 hours

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to display listings from my database where the row `creation` (which is a timestamp) is after 12 hours from "NOW".

I've found a lot of documentation on within a timeframe, e.g:

```
WHERE `date` <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

But I can't figure out how to SELECT when a row is after 12 hours. (Keeping everything that was created within 12 hours not selected)

Any help would be really appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: If you edit, try to add *EDIT* and add what you want to change below. Makes it easier to see what has changed now.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more details? You want to select rows that have `date` set to later than 12 hours from now, or you just need to add also a column determining whether something has `date` set to later than 12 hours from now?

Comment: I'm just looking to SELECT all the rows that were created more than 12 hours from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `select * from table where creation > unix_timestamp() + 43200`

Comment: That will select records, which have a create date (as a timestamp which you said) that is 12 hours **after** the current date.

Comment: This is how I wrote: $listing = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `temp_users` WHERE `creation` > unix_timestamp() + 43200") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I don't want to doubt your timestamp, but can you paste a timestamp example... I'm guessing either.. your timestamps were generated on a different server so they are out of sync, or 2) your timestamp is a Javscript timestamp.. which includes milliseconds.

Comment: (PHP Timestamps) and that's a fair request. Timestamp: 1302411600

Comment: Then you should generate your timestamp also in PHP, to avoid potentiall issues with the mysql server not running on the same timezone.

Comment: I am generating them in PHP :/

Comment: @Alexwin what about timezone on your mysql server and web server? Are they the same?

Comment: I think you may have been right, I threw a quick "date_default_timezone_set" and I think it's working now, Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Alexwhin My answer was below :)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

If you need only records that created more than 12 hours ago

```
select * from table where creation <= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
```

If you need only records that created during last 12 hours

```
select * from table where creation >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
```

Comment: Post your DB schema with some sample data please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND now();